# Cors headers not handled properly ( http requests are fine, but socke.io connections not)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cors

anybody could help me out with this. The code below is not handling cors properly. When i send http request the headers coming back are fine, however trying to get a connection through socket.io-client i get no cors headers in response. Anybody knows why is that happening and how to fix it?

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require('http')
const app = express();
const socket = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send({e: 'elo'})
})
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("user connected to: ")
});
io.on("message", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
server.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket IO handles CORS separately than express. See the following:

socket.io v2 [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v2/handling-cors/)

```js
const io = socket(server, {
  origins: ["https://example.com"]
});
```

socket.io v3 [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/)

```js
const io = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

In your case, you would pass `*` to the `origin` or `origins` property (depending on the version you are using) to allow all origins. Although locking it down to certain origins is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I went through 10 different threads on this matter and couln't find an answer, and this helps, appreciate this!

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to help. Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. Thanks!